# Search for a given row in a table

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the difference between regular expression Modifier 'i' and 'm'.
Example:

```
var str = "Visit W3Schools";
var patt1 = /w3schools/i;
document.write(str.match(patt1));

 var str = "Visit W3Schools";
 var patt1 = /w3schools/m;
 document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, it's kinda hard to see what you're asking, but I think what you want is

```
new RegExp('1.*'+str,'i');
```

The period (.) matches any character and the * matches any character zero or more times.  I'm not 100% on the syntax of that regex in javascript, but that should be a minor issue.  Maybe a str.toString() is missing or something?

Comment: I suggest using `new RegExp('1\d*: '+str, 'i');`.

Comment: Yup, that would be better.  @Jayant - \d matches numerical digits.